# Dyanmic boxes for kitchen display

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I am making an order screen for a kitchen (for examples just search for "kitchen display" on Google). The boxes are working, but they inherit the height of the first order.

[image]

See how order 2 and 3 both have lest item (bullets points) than order one but still have the same height. What I would like is that the have their own size depending on what is inside the box. Just like the kitchen display example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/kitchen.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Order Management</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: white;
            padding-left: 340px;
        }
        .order-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap; /* Allow boxes to wrap to the next row */
        }
        .order-box {
            border: 2px solid #000;
            border-radius: 20px;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px;
            width: 200px;
        }
        h2 {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Order Management</h1>
    <form action="/create_order" method="post">
        <button type="submit">Create New Order</button>
    </form>
    <div class="order-container">
        {% for order_id, items in orders.items() %}
        <div class="order-box" id="order-{{ order_id }}">
            <h2>Order {{ order_id }}</h2>
            <ul>
                {% for item in items %}
                <li>{{ item }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            <form action="/add_item" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="{{ order_id }}">
                <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Add item">
                <button type="submit" onclick="resizeOrderBox({ order_id })">Add Item</button>
            </form>
            <form action="/delete_order" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="{{ order_id }}">
                <button type="submit">Delete Order</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <script>
        // Function to set the order box height based on its content
        function resizeOrderBox(orderId) {
            const orderBox = document.getElementById(`order-${orderId}`);
            const ul = orderBox.querySelector('ul');
            ul.style.height = 'auto';
            const newHeight = ul.offsetHeight;
            ul.style.height = '';
            orderBox.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Flask:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

# Store the orders in a dictionary for simplicity (You can use a database for a real application)
orders = {}

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', orders=orders)

@app.route('/create_order', methods=['POST'])
def create_order():
    order_id = len(orders) + 1
    orders[order_id] = []  # Initialize the new order with an empty list
    return render_template('index.html', orders=orders)

@app.route('/add_item', methods=['POST'])
def add_item():
    order_id = int(request.form['order_id'])
    item = request.form['item']
    orders[order_id].append(item)
    return render_template('index.html', orders=orders)

@app.route('/delete_order', methods=['POST'])
def delete_order():
    order_id = int(request.form['order_id'])
    if order_id in orders:
        del orders[order_id]
    return render_template('index.html', orders=orders)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Flask isn't necessarily used in this case, so it doesn't need to be in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your box a specific height

```
.order-box{
    height:fit-content;
 }
```

And you're good to go.